# Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше отправляем и получаем ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но, в бд сохраняется запись и при следующем запуске мы можем её видеть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Reviews.cshtml:**

```html
<script src="~/scripts/CommentsAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<form onsubmit="return false" action="/Home/Reviews" method="POST">
    <fields>
        <p>Оставьте отзыв :)</p>
        <input type="text" name="Name" id="name" placeholder="Введите ваше имя" required /><br />

        <input type="text" name="Comment"  id="comment"  required  /><br />

        <input type="submit" />
    </fields>
</form>
@foreach (var b in ViewBag.UserComments)
{
    <hr/>
        <p>@b.UserName</p>
        <p>@b.UserText</p>
    <hr/>
}
```

**HomeController.cs:**

```
  public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        CommentContext db = new CommentContext();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Reviews()
        {

            IEnumerable<UserComments> comments = db.UserComments;
            ViewBag.UserComments = comments;


            return View(db.UserComments);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Reviews(string Name,string Comment)
        {
            UserComments user = new UserComments
            {
                UserName = Name,
                UserText = Comment,


            };
            db.UserComments.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return View();
        }
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
```

**CommentAjax.js:**

```js
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function () {

    var UserName = $('input[name=Name]').val();
    var UserComment = $('input[name=Comment]').val();
  

    SubmitForm(UserName, UserComment);
        

});

function SubmitForm(name, comment) {

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/Home/Reviews",
        data: { Name: name, Comment: comment }
    })
 
   .done(function () {
       alert("Спасибо за отзыв ");
   }).fail(function () {
       alert("Ошибка" );
   });
   
}
```

БД:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно исправить ?

Comment: Все дело во времени жизни объекта `ViewBag.UserComments`, которое ограничивается одним запросом. Из-за того что Ваше представление ожидает `ViewBag.UserComments` с находящейся в ней коллекции, которой там нет, Ваше приложение и "падает". Вам требуется в Вашем `Httpost` методе заново инициализировать Ваш `ViewBag.UserComments`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Представление `Reviews` ожидает назначенный `ViewBag.UserComments`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Reviews(string Name,string Comment)
{
    UserComments user = new UserComments
    {
        UserName = Name,
        UserText = Comment,
    };
    db.UserComments.Add(user);
    db.SaveChanges();

    ViewBag.UserComments = db.UserComments; // !!!

    return View();
}
```